# Using aws-virtual-gpu-device-plugin on non AWS Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I read about [aws virtual gpu device plugin](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-virtual-gpu-device-plugin), how this can be used to split one GPU into multiple smaller GPUs and run concurrent jobs on each small part. While this is wonderful for my use case, I want to know if this works only with AWS EKS service or can be used on other cloud provider K8 clusters as well? Has anyone used it on non-aws infrastructure?

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware of its limitations.

[Virtual GPU device plugin for Kubernetes](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-virtual-gpu-device-plugin)

> Blockquote
> Limitations
> This solution is build on top of Volta Multi-Process Service(MPS). You can only use it on instances types with Tesla-V100 or newer. (Only Amazon EC2 P3 Instances and Amazon EC2 G4 Instances now)
> Virtual GPU device plugin by default set GPU compute mode to EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS which means GPU is assigned to MPS process, individual process threads can submit work to GPU concurrently via MPS server. This GPU can not be used for other purpose.
> Virtual GPU device plugin only on single physical GPU instance like P3.2xlarge if you request k8s.amazonaws.com/vgpu more than 1 in the workloads.
> Virtual GPU device plugin can not work with Nvidia device plugin together. You can label nodes and use selector to install Virtual GPU device plugin.